# mdy {lubridate} unable to identify "January"

Tags: r, lubridate

I am working with a list of birth dates in the format "January131973". To get the dates from this string, I am using `mdy` function from `lubridate` library. Strangely the code was returning NA only for dates in January, but working fine for other months, as below

```
> mdy("January131973")
[1] NA
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found. 
> mdy("April241973")
[1] "1973-04-24"
```

The data spans across all months and dates, and years ranging from 1971 to 1990. But the error occurs only for dates in January. I have worked around the input string to get "13January1973" and proceeded with `dmy` function instead, which has resolved the issue at hand. (`ymd` also works perfectly fine.)

However, if it can be verified that I am not overlooking any underlying conflicts etc, it will be helpful the next times, and can also help identify unseen issues elsewhere.

Here is a test code I have tried out to check different combinations

```
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
x <- data.frame(mmm=month.name, dd=c(15:26), yyyy=c(1973:1984))
x_mdy <- unite(x, test, mmm,dd,yyyy, sep = "",remove = FALSE)
lapply(x_mdy$test, mdy)
x_dmy <- unite(x, test, dd,mmm,yyyy, sep = "", remove = FALSE)
lapply(x_dmy$test, dmy)
x_ymd <- unite(x, test, yyyy,mmm,dd, sep = "", remove = FALSE)
lapply(x_ymd$test, ymd)
```

After running the above code, I have faced the issue only while using `mdy` with "January". Also note that abbreviated form of the month name also gives the same error (`mmm=month.abb` in the above df creation.)

Any clarification of this behavior appreciated.

Comment: Bug report? Goes to: `maintainer('lubridate')` 
[1] "Vitalie Spinu <spinuvit@gmail.com>"

Comment: `as.Date` handles it fine: `as.Date("January131973", '%B%d%Y')`. You can also pass the same parsing string to `parse_date_time` to get it to function properly (though giving it `'mdy'` fails in the same way): `parse_date_time("January131973", '%B%d%Y')`

Comment: It's a bug which stranglly enough occurs only with januarry. Bug report opened at the github [tracker](https://github.com/hadley/lubridate/issues/411)